# Mac OS X: hosts file changes don't persist

Tags: macos, mac, hosts

On my Mac OS X 10.5.7 system I've installed and uninstalled GasMask (a utility to manage hosts files) at some point. Ever since then, when I manually edit my hosts file (which I furthermore manually recreated after uninstalling GasMask) the changes don't persist when I reboot the machine. Any idea what is going on here?

Furthermore, what steps could I undertake to revert to the vanilla state from before I had GasMask installed? I think some config changes from this  GasMask installation might be the root of my current problem.

Thanks.

Comment: are you making the changes as `root` or your normal user?

Comment: @warren: I edit my hosts file with TextWrangler. Upon editing, TextWrangler asks me whether I want to unlock the file for editing. Then when I want to save changes it asks me for a password, which I presume is suppoed to be the root password. I enter the password, and the file is saved. Owner of the hosts file is root, group wheel. BTW, the file shows a @ sign next to the files modes when I do a `ls -l` in terminal. Don't know whether this is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep -r GasMask /Library` and `find /Library -name "*GasMask*"`

It's possible there's some plists laying around somewhere.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into this, and report back when I get the chance. Cheers.

Comment: BTW, if I do find these plists; do I need to delete these? Or do I need some in depth knowledge of plists before I start messing with them?

Comment: It should be safe to just delete any GasMask plists that you find. They'll just be created if you ever run GasMask again.